# Backup processs always showing "in progress" and 0% completed

Tags: backup

I have automated my SharePoint 2010 server daily backup operation by running a service and the backup location will point to D:\Automatic_Backup\  folder location. This service will take the backup by running stsadm command.

Last week i have upgraded sql server running in the same server from express edition to Enterprise edition. On the same day the back up operation was failed and bellow is the error message.

Access to the path D:\Automatic_Backup\spbrtoc.xml is denied for account yyyyyyyyyyyy\xxxxxxx. Ensure that the SharePoint Timer service and Microsoft SQL Server service accounts have Full Control permission on both the file share and the underlying folder.

But i am doing all these using administrator account only.

After that i have tried to take the fullback up manually, but it is always showing in progress status and not moving to completed status.
Also i have checked the currently running jobs from Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Check Job Status -> Running Jobs , all the jobs are showing In Progress with 0 % completed.

I have given below the link for the image which shows the Backup & Restore job status and backup history. In the image you can see under readiness

1. No backup or Restore in progress &

Backup process is already running.

And in the backup history you can see all the currently running jobs which do not shows any finshed time and all these jobs are in In Progress status.

http://nzcgqq.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pDtsWYRr37XBoxzN9MMxQOBRHfx8-GvEAHCSmDXicfd_P3PgA96XBR8QMRSgrZ3OpQEF6QbU-BkJr0nYQ6zncz52LPjo6jXu3/BackUp%20Problem.png?psid=1

Please give any suggestions to fix this issue and to take a Full Backup successfully.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is consistent with a permissions issue on the target backup directory. A couple of suggestions:

As a first step you will need to go in and delete any "In Progress" backup timer jobs. Unfortunately they tend to hang around.

Attempt to perform the backup again, but look at the backup log if it exists in the backup directory, or check the event logs and ULS. This should help you check the permissions, which I think are the likely cause of the problem.

Comment: My back up logs showing the below contents at the bottom.
[4/19/2011 5:06:15 AM] Verbose: [WSS_Content] SQL Server Message: BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 587362 pages in 280.838 seconds (16.339 MB/sec).
[4/19/2011 5:06:15 AM] Verbose: [WSS_Content] SQL command completed at: 4/19/2011 5:06:15 AM.
Earlier the final message will be "Backup Process completed succussfully". But in this one it looks like after that its not getting progressed. Also in the above image link, you can see none of the backup completed successfully. Also its not showing any failure message.

Comment: You might want to also try granting "Everyone" access to the backup directory as a temporary troubleshooting measure. Any problem's I've had with backups have always been permissions related as SPDoctor suggests.